# How to force QtCreator to load a pro.user file?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have set up extensive build (10+) configurations (per my project's requirements) as well as deployment and "run" configurations for my project. This project is based on an external harddrive that is moved between two machines. The problem is that every time I move the hdd, QtC wants to erase all my settings and start over from scratch.

How do I force QtC to load my project settings? Right now I have had to start over because, without me having to click "save" anywhere, QtC overwrote all of my settings the moment I opened my project with no warning.

I suppose I don't even have to force it to load the file. I would be fine if I just knew what it was in the *.pro.user file that tips QtC off that it should ignore me (and common sense) and nuke my work for no reason. If I knew that, I could manually cut and paste over my settings from .user file to .user file. I have already tried manually updating two fields int he *.user file called "EnvironmentId" & "FileVersion", but QtC somehow still magically knows I want it to trash my project.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sad but true. Consider switching to cmake. It will store many settings in the CMakeCache.txt file and Qt Creator will have less power over them.

Comment: The way I deal with this is not relying on *.user files at all. I put build configurations directly in the project file and switch between them using the CONFIG variable.

Comment: @NikosC. I don't understand, the ".pro" file? What can you store in it? Please explain this sorcery in detail, good sir!

Comment: Depends on what you want. In my case, I do different builds depending on the OS and whether I want debug or release builds. For example, here's the project file of one of my apps: https://raw.github.com/realnc/qtads/master/qtads.pro There's conditional code in some places in there that sets different compiler options, preprocessor macros and compiles different files, depending on the OS. But you should probably expand your question and include more info about what exactly it is you want to do.

Comment: I understand you now. No, that's not a solution I care to take. I'm just going to dump the IDE entirely. I'm am getting literally 0 use out of it. There are not any longer any tasks whatsoever I would go to the IDE to complete. This is totally unbelievable, but, at this point, I will just write a shellscript and edit in Kate.

Thanks for your help though. I could have wasted A LOT of time screwing around with Qt.

Comment: @Pavel It is not true, as you can actually do it. See my post underneath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, actually Qt Creator does support shared .pro files.
This link: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-sharing-project-settings.html shows how to do it.
So, no reason to switch to shell scripts :-)

**Note**: Qt (and Qt Creator) is an open source project. Everyone is free to add improvements to the code. Remember that Qt is free, and we should all be very thankful for that. It is one of the greatest C++ libraries in existence. It is maintained by a large number of volunteers, and, yes, there still some 'annoyances' and bugs in there. Please file your complaints on the [Qt bug tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG), no need for ranting.

Comment: I asked this in June 30th. While I now love you, this is SO endemic of how Qt does everything. How did you even know there WAS such a thing as .pro.shared files?